# Regex splitting

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to implement function which will split block of text to substrings. 
The condition of split is to each block has to begin with a digit on the first postion of line.

For example:

1. Mike was ill but he went to school
2. The bees have nest near my house
3. StackOverflow is very helpfull.

This is my code:

```
 private static string[]SplitStringOnBlocks(string text)
    {
        string pattern = @"^d";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        return rgx.Split(text);              

    }
```

But it doesn't split the text

Comment: what does it return instead? the whole string/text?

Comment: It returns the whole string

Comment: It does. It's a numbered question list

Comment: A digit is matched with `\d`: `@"^\d"`. What is your required output?

Comment: Oh, I see. you're right

Comment: Judging by the accepted answer, there was just a typo in the OP code - I suggest closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong. You need to escape the `d` to `\d` and you need to enable multilining.

Correct pattern:
[`^\d`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd&i=1.+Mike+was+ill+but+he+went+to+school%0d%0a2.+The+bees+have+nest+near+my+house%0d%0a3.+StackOverflow+is+very+helpfull.&o=m)

Change creation of regex to:
`new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)`

Comment: I do not believe this will work "as expected". However, *expected* behavior is not defined yet :)

Comment: @vortexture: Why does it work? It removes the digit. Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/NxKYzW).

Comment: @stribizhev If vortexture don't want to split the digits away he could split with newlines. I think (but I'm not sure) it will be okay to split them away.

Comment: @Verarind: I voted to close this question as it is unclear to all future readers and - judging by the fact your answer is accepted - there was just a typo in the OP code.